# How do I display tabular data on smaller screen sizes

Tags: html, mobile, html-table

I am working on a website which is currently fixed width and converting it to a responsive layout.

The website contains a few tables which I cannot get rid of, as the information contained within them is definitely tabular data

The problem i am having, is that when you shrink the screen size down, the table will only shrink to a certain point, and then the amount of content within each `<td>` just won't allow the table to shrink any further, thus requiring the user to have to zoom in on these particular pages.

Now, i thought perhaps I could strip the table out for smaller screen sizes and enable a function to allow the user to download the information contained within these tables, as say a `pdf`. But i have been designing/developing on the principle that all users should receive the same experience irrelevant of their screen size i.e. not removing content at smaller screen sizes.

Does anyone have any advice or example of where tables have been implemented well for smaller screens?

Comment: How small are you trying to shrink it down to??  Almost sounds like you're allowing it to shrink too small.  I'd employ a "min-width" css rule (which admittedly isn't a 100% solution (IE) but is a start).